# Is there a mob that can generate new crimson, similar to the corruptor?

Tags: terraria

Most of the Question ist already in the title ;)

Until now, i only have seen two new enemies in the Crimson, after entering Hardmode:

[Herpling](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Herpling)

[Floaty Gross](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Floaty_Gross)

None of these enemies create new crimson biome, as far as i can tell. I might have been too busy running away though...

Is there an equivalent enemy to the corruptor? Or is this one thing less to worry about?

Comment: http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crimson lists 3 other hardmode enemies - Ichor Sticker, Blood Jelly, and Blood Feeder. Unable to verify if any of those spread crimson.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, none of the Crimson enemies spread Crimson like Corruptors.  In fact, as of patch 1.2, Corruptors no longer spread Corruption.